# react-navigation navigate is not a function error. - Class component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-component

I'm using react native class component and I'm using react-navigation to route in the app. the guide is mostly for the functional component and I'm trying to implement it with class components. but when i trying to get it from reactnavigation it always throws me error that navigation is not a function or undefined. Im sorry if this is an already asked question as I'm really new to this react native.

class component

```
import React from 'react';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { Button, Divider, Layout, TopNavigation ,Card,Text} from '@ui-kitten/components';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

     navigateDetails(navigation)  {
         debugger
         navigation('Details');
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props);
        this.state = { hover: false };
    }

    render()  {
        const navigation = this.props;
        return(

            <Button onPress={this.navigateDetails}>OPEN DETAILS</Button>

        );
    }
}

export default function (props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return <HomeScreen {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

Comment: change ```onPress``` function as ```<Button onPress={this.props.navigation.navigate('Details')}>```

Comment: @SDushan i was trying to achive this using a wrapped function. seems I have to pass that navigation to the function as a variable in order to work. onPress={()=>this.navigateDetails(navigation)} Thanks, lot for your comment and details

Comment: Since you are already inside the class component you can access navigation props directly & don't' have to pass ```navigation``` as a param.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have to pass that navigation to the function as a variable in order to work. so I have changed the function as bellow to pass the navigation to the 
function and also changed `this.navigateDetails(navigation)` to 
`()=>this.navigateDetails(navigation)`

also, I destructed the navigation like `const {navigation} = this.props;`

full code line

```
 onPress={()=>this.navigateDetails(navigation)}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to make sure navigation prop is exist in your class component (As looking in your code its already exist) and the second thing is `this.props.navigation` is an object, not a function which holds different function like `navigate, push` etc so you have to execute these functions, here are some changes I did in your code and I hope this will work for you.

```
   class HomeScreen extends React.Component { 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props);
        this.state = { hover: false };
       }
        navigateDetails()  {
         this.props.navigation.navigate('Details');
       };

    render()  {
        const navigation = this.props;
        return(

            <Button onPress={()=>this.navigateDetails()}>OPEN DETAILS</Button>

        );
    }
}

export default function (props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    return <HomeScreen {...props} navigation={navigation} />;
}
```

Comment: it throws the same error which is cannot read property navigate of undefined

Comment: Hi, I have fixed it like this. seems I have to pass that navigation to the function as a variable in order to work. onPress={()=>this.navigateDetails(navigation)} Thanks, lot for your comment and details

Comment: @ThilinaDinithFonseka now you can accept the answer which you think is most closer to your problem.

Comment: your answer was not working for me. please check the answer below I have explained.

Comment: okay, because I don't have any workable demo I can only predict the solution, good to know if you found the solution.